# populating sheet2 using macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am an excel novice. I am trying to write macros to populate sheet2 based on sheet one. I have following columns on sheet1:
Name CustomName CustomeValue
a    Bay        11
a    Site       UK
a    Rack       3
b    Site       UK
b    Rack       2
C    empty      empty

Sheet 2 - output should be as follows
Name Bay Site Rack 
a    11  UK   3
b        UK   2
c

I did try to write macros to match row by row and compare and populate selectively, but the script randomly populates when huge date comes in, Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Code snippet:

```
Sub populatingsheet2()

    x = 2
    y = 2 
    Sheet2.Cells(y, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) 
    Do While x <= 4 

        If Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(x + 1, 1) Then 

            ‘I want unique records 
            'MsgBox "Identical" 
            If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "Bay" Then 
                Sheet2.Cells(y, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 3) 
            End If 
            If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "Site" Then 
                Sheet2.Cells(y, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 3) 
            End If 
            If Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) = "Rack" Then 
                Sheet2.Cells(y, 4) = Sheet1.Cells(x, 3) 
            End If 

        Else: 'MsgBox "Not Identical" 
        End If 
        x = x + 1 
        y = y + 1 

    Loop 

End Sub
```

Comment: You could show us what you have. We could try to improve it and be able to understand your situation better.

Comment: why not start by activating the macro recorder (**Tools>Macro>Record New Macro...**), then doing actions like copy and paste one cell, a range of cells, an entire row, an entire column, and finally, copy a worksheet before deactivating/turning off the recorder. This will give you some code to look at and play around with. After that, we can help you improve your own code, rather than giving you our code!

Comment: Thanks KazJaw and Philip: My script was working until now, doing some basic stuff but now it has completely corrupted. I will soon give you what i have done. so that you guys can help me.

Comment: Hi,Please find the snippet of the code, And it is not working. However this is the logic i want:

Comment: are you trying to transpose?

Comment: Yes, Kind of of transpose but not fully. I am basically checking for the value on sheet1 and populating it on the respective columns on sheet2.

Answer (score 1):

so, have you considered you could do all that using Formulas on Sheet 2 without a macro?

maybe like this in Sheet 2 Colummn B:

```
=IF(Sheet1!B:B="Bay",Sheet1!C:C,"")
```

in column C

```
=IF(Sheet1!B:B="Site",SHeet1!C:C,"")
```

hth

Philip